# Windows 10 Bash not working

Tags: windows-10, bash

My Windows 10 Bash not working, the cmd show the next text:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bash
-- Función beta --
Esta opción instalará Ubuntu en Windows. Te lo proporciona Canonical
con licencia de acuerdo con sus términos disponibles aquí:
https://aka.ms/uowterms

La aplicación que intenta ejecutar no se admite en esta versión de Windows.
```

I translate the last line

```
The application you are trying to run is not supported on this version of Windows
```

The Windows 10 compiled version is 14393.447 Enterprise 1607

How is the trouble?

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you had the opportunity to check with your Domain Admin personnel?  I am fairly certain they have disabled access to Bash and/or the Windows Store.

Comment: Hi! I am near! I followed the [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/stop-employees-from-using-the-windows-store) but in the last step, the W10 lunch a error and closes the windows. I tried run "wsreset" how admin but show "access denied".

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Hi Run5k!! Thank for your help! I continue without solve the issues. Now I am tring a clean install in a Virtual Machine

Answer (score 1):

Just to double-check, are you running a 32-bit version of Windows 10?  If so, I am afraid that [Bash isn't available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/04/06/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-download-now-3/).

If you are running a 64-bit version of Windows 10, did you already enable the feature within the `Turn Windows features on or off` interface?

[image: Bash]

([Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/))

Comment: Hi! I have enable its option. But not work

Comment: And you already ensured that you are **not** running the 32-bit version of Windows 10?  [Microsoft Windows Determine 32-bit or 64-bit Version](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21726/how-do-i-know-if-im-running-32-bit-or-64-bit-windows-answers/)

Comment: Yes, I use 64-bit system!

Comment: Did you complete the proper procedures to install and use Bash?  [How to Install and Use the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Yes, I followed the procedure until run "bash". But I have not the option download how show the procedure

Comment: My apologies, but I don't quite understand what you mean.  Did you read the tutorial found on the web page I referenced in my previous comment?

Comment: The procedure falls in this line `The first time you run the bash.exe file, you’ll be prompted to accept the terms of service. The command will then download the “Bash on Ubuntu on Windows” application from the Windows Store.` The console show 'The application you are trying to run is not supported on this version of Windows'.

Comment: You said that you are running Windows 10 version *"14393.447 Enterprise 1607."*  The fact that you are running an Enterprise version means that additional restrictions may be stopping you from using Bash. Your Domain Admin personnel may be blocking Bash specifically with AppLocker, or they also have the capability to [block access to the Windows Store](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/stop-employees-from-using-the-windows-store) itself.  One way or the other, I am rather certain that is the root cause of the problem.  You need to check with your Domain Admin folks.

Answer (score 0):

You are running W10 Enterprise and likely LTBS. 
If that is the case note that LTBS versions do not include Windows Store and lack any beta features even if the system preferences allow you to.You should consider a different version.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** [Since Windows 10 Fall Creators update (FCU) the bash feature has been taken out of beta.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/07/28/windows-subsystem-for-linux-out-of-beta/) you can now use bash and ubuntu on windows 10 again if you wish.

On Microsofts Repo BashOnWindows you will find the following issue:  [app that you are trying to run is not supported on this version of Windows #1448](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1448)

In it this explanation is provided

> The beta was accidentally included in the LTSB release. It was
>   subsequently disabled because it cannot be updated or even bugfixed
>   without updating the kernel-mode drivers lxcore.sys and lxss.sys, both
>   of which are strictly bound to specific versions of the Windows kernel
>   (for example, work on networking to support some WSL features was
>   transported into the kernel-mode "Winsock Kernel" core module of the
>   NT kernel, where it will also be used to provide more socket
>   functionality to the Win32 usermode Winsock API as well).
>
> The drivers lxcore.sys and lxss.sys (being beta components) are being
>   maintained directly along the "Fast ring" of the Insider branch of
>   Windows 10. The "slow ring" provides snapshots of the "fast ring", and
>   the Current Branch will be replaced roughly this April by another fork
>   of the Insider branch. Until the Windows Subsystem for Linux loses its
>   "beta" tag, it will only be available (updates, bugfixes, etc) in the
>   Current Branch as a snapshot of its state at the date of the fork,
>   without even bugfixes being backported to the current branch from the
>   Insider Branch.
>
> Given that even the Current Branch is not currently receiving
>   bugfixes, upgrades, or likely even security fixes, it would be
>   impossible to handle bugfixes in LTSB (releases scheduled 2-3 years
>   apart!) of a feature that is highly incomplete and has already hit
>   several bugchecks (many bugchecks are also potential security
>   vulnerabilities, and it is dangerous to use buggy drivers in
>   kernel-mode).
>
> So a decision was taken by Microsoft to remove this feature from LTSB
>   until it is out of beta, at which point it will at least have bugs and
>   security vulnerabilities fixed and backported. On the other hand, this
>   also means that LTSB will not be receiving this functionality in
>   stable form until at least 2018 if not 2019.
>
> If you want to use WSL, it is highly recommended to run Insider builds
>   or at the very least the Current Branch, which receives updates
>   roughly every nine months.

Long story short... unless you are doing Windows Insider for beta testing windows 10 you will not have access to this feature of windows until the beta ends in 2018 or 2019.

An alternative to joining the Windows Insider program would be to set up a virtual machine running Ubuntu